# AngularJS: Construct ui-states from array of template strings

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have static template files (around 50) and I would like to construct ui-states from these template array

```
var templates = ['index.html','about.html','contact.html','careers.html']
```

and my state would simply go like this :

```
$stateProvider
.state('index',{url:'/index.html',templateUrl:'templates/index.html'}) 
.state('about',{url:'/about.html',templateUrl:'templates/about.html'})
.state('contact',{url:'/contact.html',templateUrl:'templates/contact.html'})
```

Can I achieve like this?

```
templates.forEach(function(template){
 $stateProvider.state(template,{url:'/'+template,templateUrl:'templates/'+template}) 
})
```

Comment: probaly you can do this, but you have to do it with `.config`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess like this,

```
angular.forEach(templates, function (temp) {
   $stateProvider.state(temp,{
        url:'/' + temp,
        templateUrl:'templates/'+ temp}) 
});
```

But after this you need to configure this with `.config`

```
angular.module('app', [])
     .config({
      // you can add $stateprovider here
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

simply forEach through your templates and create a state per each template

```
var templates = [
      'index.html',
      'about.html',
      'contact.html'
    ];

    templates.forEach(function(tmp){
      $stateProvider
        .state(tmp,{
          url:'/'+tmp,
          templateUrl:tmp
        })
    })
```